# Inline Definition and Declaration

Tags: c#, vb.net, object-initializers

Ok, im sure im mis-wording the concept but here it is anyways.

I know in CSharp you can do

```
el.AppendChild(new UISize(file, "TSize") { CX = 95, CY = 20 });
```

which declares a temporary bucket variable and then assigns the associate property values to the variable.  Which then sends it to the `XMLElement` `AppendChild` method.

1. What is this design concept called?
2. What is the conversion to VB.Net?

I have tried using my own online utility that does a 90-95% conversion rate from C# <-> VB.Net.  It has failed in this instance, and so need a hand-up on what i am looking to do to convert this from C# to VB.Net.

I would really like to not have to do a long-declaration of a variable with assignments, if at all possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is using *object initializers* in C#. The syntax to do the same is subtly different in VB

```
var uiSize = new UISize(file, "TSize") { CY = 95, CY = 20 }; // C#
Dim uiSize = New UISize(file, "TSize") With {.CX = 95, .CY = 20} ' VB
```

And, of course, you can inline the instantiation of the object inside a method call as well.

```
someObject.SomeMethod(New UISize(file, "TSize") With {.CX = 95, .CY = 20})
```

For more on using object initializers in Visual Basic, [consult this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx).